# Arbitrary Number of File Uploads in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, http-upload

What is the best way to allow a user to do an arbitrary number of file uploads with Django?

If I knew I was going to allow the user to do up to two file uploads then I could just do this in my `forms.py`...

```
from django import forms

class UploaderForm(forms.Form):
    file1 = forms.FileField(upload_to='user_files')
    file2 = forms.FileField(upload_to='user_files')
```

...and this in my `views.py`...

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploaderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        # do something.
else:
    form = UploaderForm()
...
```

However, I'm planning on using Javascript on the frontend to allow the user to continually add new `<input type="file" name="fileN" />` elements (where N is the Nth file upload field added to the page.) The user can choose to do their upload with one or more files selected.

Is there any way that I can use Django's built in forms to accomplish this?

If, as I suspect, I can't utilize Django forms to generate the forms, can I use Django's validation? i.e., it would be handy to be able to access `form.cleaned_data['file0']`, `form.cleaned_data['file1']`, etc., instead of having to do my own validation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formsets are exactly what you need.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets

All you have to do is follow the field naming format that the formset uses `'form-0-field'` in your javascript instead of `fileN`

Also modify the `form-TOTAL_FORMS` accordingly. Check the docs, they are especially thorough on this one.

```
class UploaderForm(forms.Form):
    file1 = forms.FileField(upload_to='user_files')


from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
UploaderFormset = formset_factory(UploaderForm)

# long as you specify 'form-TOTAL_FORMS' and 2 other fields listed in the docs,
# the formset will auto generate form instances & populate with fields based on
# their 0 index.
formset = UploaderFormset(request.POST)

for form in formset.forms:
    form.save()
```

The best part is that this ties into validation perfectly, and you could even re-display your forms for error messages (which would be a bit of a pain if you were only generating html via ajax)

Comment: Dude. Sweet. That looks like exactly what I need. I'd heard of Django Formsets, but have yet to use them. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, no prob! Yeah, it's ridiculously useful